# Is there a linter for fish like there is for bash with shellcheck?

Tags: debugging, fish

For sh/bash/zsh there is https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck however there won't be support for fish with it https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/209 - is there any linters for fish?

Comment: Faho already provided an excellent answer but I wanted to point out that fish has a `fish_indent` command which utilizes the fish parser to do for fish code what tools like `gofmt` does for go-lang and `clang-format` does for C/C++. That tool could form the basis for a `fish_lint` command. Anyone sufficiently motivated is encouraged to roll up their sleeves and write the code to implement such a command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is not (and obviously this is impossible to prove).

And if someone were to create such a thing, there'd need to be consensus about what the "typical beginner's syntax issues" and "semantic problems that cause a shell to behave strangely and counter-intuitively" are.

Fish doesn't have many of POSIX sh's warts (as it was written as a reaction to them). Some examples from the [shellcheck README](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/README.md):

```
echo $1                           # Unquoted variables
```

Fish's quoting behavior is quite different - in particular, there is no word splitting on variables, so unquoted variables *usually* do what you want.

```
v='--verbose="true"'; cmd $v      # Literal quotes in variables
```

This is presumably an (unsuccessful) attempt to defeat word splitting, which isn't necessary.

This example nicely illustrates the issue - there are multiple decades worth of sh scripts. The flaws and unintuitive behaviors are really well known. So well known in fact, that the common-but-incorrect workarounds are known as well. That's just not the case for fish.

(Obviously, other examples do apply to fish as well, especially the "Frequently misused commands" section.)

---

Some things in fish that I know new users often trip over:

- Unquoted variables expand to one argument per element in the list (since every variable is one). That includes zero if the list is empty, which is an issue with `test` - e.g. `test -n $var` will return 0 because fish's test builtin is one of the few parts that are POSIX-compatible (since POSIX demands test with one argument returns 0). Double-quote if you always need one argument.
- `{}` expands to nothing and `{x}` expands to "x", which means `find -exec` needs quoting, as do some git commit-ishes (`HEAD@{4}`). (edit: This has since been changed, `{}` expands to `{}` and `{x}` expands to `{x}` unless x has a comma or other expansion, so `HEAD@{4}` works)

Comment: author has a sense of humor. shwarts! :D

Answer (score 4):

`fish -n` or `--no-execute` *"does not execute any commands, only performs syntax checking"*, so you could do something [like what I am doing here](https://github.com/vorburger/LearningLinux/compare/fish-scripts):

```
for f in **/*.fish; do fish -n "$f"; done
```